# Javascript on masterpage returns undefined

Tags: 2013, javascript

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("FetchURL");
                function FetchURL()
                {
                    // Custom JavaScript methods
                   var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
        var site = ctx.get_site();
        ctx.load(site);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(s, a){ currURL=SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl("");
                                            });
                    }
```

The above method returns the URL, however, sometimes it returns undefined, which causes errors. How to tackle this?

Code is placed in head of the masterpage... in scripts tag.

Comment: do you need to call get_site for anything? otherwise there is no need to load it with ctx.load; you can call the SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl synchronously, without calling executeQueryAsync

Comment: What returns `undefined`? The function FeetchURL has no return and will then always return `underfined`. The global variable `currURL` will be set asynchronously, as `ctx.executeQueryAsync` is asynchronous, which means  in you code you can't know when it is set

Comment: @MdMazzotti alert(SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl()); doesnot work. can you give me a solution, eirikb.

Comment: @variable it's a function, you must call it like SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl()

Comment: If i put the SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl  in the spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames() then it works, why is this happening? Im confused

Comment: @variable because it's defined inside the sp.js file. You need to make sure the file has been loaded before calling it

Comment: MdMazzoti, I got around 100lines of js code, is it good practice to put all of it in execute or delay untill sp.js is loaded?

Comment: try using `_spPageContextInfo.layoutsUrl` instead. http://blah.winsmarts.com/2013-2-_sppagecontextinfo_is_your_new_best_friend.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl is contained within the sp.js file.
You have to make sure that sp.js has been loaded, before calling the function.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl', getCurrentUrl);

function getCurrentUrl(){
  currentURL = SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl(""); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for this. it works, however I am using it in a big js code, have posted the issue here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95260/executeordelayuntillscriptloadedcodetorun-sp-js-for-entire-script-function