# Create Line Basic Chart using Highcharts.js SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin, chart-web-part

I'm trying to create a graph from an external list. Since the web part doesn't available in SP 2013, I try to create a **Line Basic** chart using **Highcharts.js**

[image: This picture is taken from Highcharts.com Sample]

In my external list, there are only two columns available, which are **Date** (in DATETIME format) and **Amount** (in Decimal format). The external list always will be only consisting of 7 row of data.

After create the code, I save the javascript code at script editor webpart and html code in content editor webpart. After saving the changes, I can't find something displayed on the page.

You can find the code below. Could someone let me know where I am missing something ?  
 
Thank you :)

```
<script src="/Style%20Library/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="/Style%20Library/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="/Style%20Library/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Style%20Library/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">


<script type="text/javascript">
var splistitems;
var seriesarray = new Array();

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetChartData, "sp.js");

function GetChartData() {
 seriesarray = [];
 var currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
 var splist = currentcontext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Production');
 var splistquery = new SP.CamlQuery();
 splistitems = splist.getItems(splistquery);
 currentcontext.load(splistitems);
 currentcontext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, 
 GetChartDataSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, GetChartDataFail));
}

function GetChartDataSuccess(sender, args) {
var splistitemcount = splistitems.get_count();
if (splistitemcount != 0) {
   var splistitemenumerator = splistitems.getEnumerator();
   while (splistitemenumerator.moveNext()) {
   var currentlistitem = splistitemenumerator.get_current();
   var itemdate = currentlistitem.get_item("Date");
   var itemamount = currentlistitem.get_item("Amount");
   var seriesitem = {
                       name: itemdate,
                       data: itemamount
                   };
    seriesarray.push(seriesitem);
  }
     DrawChart();
    }
  }

function GetChartDataFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' 
    +args.get_stackTrace());
}

 function DrawChart() {
    prodChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'chart-container',
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Weekly Production'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: itemdate
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Amount'
            },
        },
         legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: false
            },
                pointStart: itemdate
    }
},
        series: [{
            name: itemdate,
            data: itemamount
        }, 
        ],

        responsive: {
        rules: [{
        condition: {
            maxWidth: 500
        },
                chartOptions: {
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'horizontal',
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                    }
                }
        }]
        }          
    });
}
</script>
```

For the HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/> 
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/highcharts.css"/><style type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="chart-container">No Production Data Found.</div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example `DrawChart` function  contains a few issues:

```
series: [{
        name: itemdate, //<- itemdate undeclared
        data: itemamount  //<-itemamount undeclared and it is expected to be a data array
},
```

`series.data` attribute expects the array of data to be provided, see [series section documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series) for a more details

The same goes to

```
xAxis: {
        categories: itemdate  //itemdate undeclared
}
```

According to [documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.categories):

> ```
> categories: Array.<String>
> ```
>
> If categories are present for the xAxis, names are used instead of
>   numbers for that axis

---

Given the input format of data the `GetChartData` function returns, you might want something like this:

```
function drawChart(data) {

    var values = data.map(function(item){
       return item.value; 
    });

    var categories = data.map(function(item){
       return item.name.getFullYear(); 
    });

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'chart-container',
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Weekly Production'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: categories
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Amount'
            },
        },
         legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: false
            },
            //pointStart: itemdate
    }
},
        series: [{
            name: 'Amount',
            data: values
        }, 
        ],

        responsive: {
        rules: [{
        condition: {
            maxWidth: 500
        },
                chartOptions: {
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'horizontal',
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                    }
                }
        }]
        }          
    });
}
```

where

```
function getChartData(success,error) {
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Production');
   var qry = new SP.CamlQuery();
   var items = list.getItems(qry);
   ctx.load(items);
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){
       var data = items.get_data().map(function(item){
            return {
                  name: item.get_item("Date"),
                  value: item.get_item("Amount")
            };
       });
       success(data);
   },error);
}


function logError(sender, args) {
    console.log(args.get_message());
}
```

Usage

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){
    getChartData(function(data){
       drawChart(data);
    },logError);
});
```

Key points:

- Prefer `SP.SOD.executeFunc` over `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded`, refer [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95260/executeordelayuntillscriptloadedcodetorun-sp-js-for-entire-script-function) on why
- `getChartData` function has been refactored

**Results**

[image]